# How to suppress mongod heartbeat output in irb

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm trying to cope with the thinly documented new 2.0 rewritten Ruby driver for Mongodb.

I want to work interactively, but the "heartbeat" monitor, which fires every 10 seconds, seems to ignore my attempts to set it to a longer period:

```
irb(main):004:0> client = Mongo::Client.new([ '127.0.0.1:27017' ], :database => 'dbname', :heartbeat_frequency => 600)
```

But precisely ten seconds later, the flood begins:

```
D, [2015-04-26T05:22:20.553320 #4123] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | COMMAND | namespace=admin.$cmd selector={:ismaster=>1} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 project=nil | runtime: 2.9023ms
=> #<Mongo::Client:0x10048740 cluster=127.0.0.1:27017>
irb(main):005:0> D, [2015-04-26T05:22:30.555284 #4123] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | COMMAND | namespace=admin.$cmd selector={:ismaster=>1} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 project=nil | runtime: 0.8411ms
```

Is there any way to stop it; it ruins the screen and makes it impossible to interact with the backend.

Comment: I discovered that if I put the first line above into a file, and then "require" the file, the suppression of errors works just fine, but then I cannot access the "client" handle to get at the mongod instance.

Comment: For future visitors, if you want beautiful colored logging similar to active record, you might want to look at the [mongo beautiful logger gem](https://github.com/ibraheemdev/mongo_beautiful_logger)

Answer (score 4):

The logger level has to be changed to other level. The default level is DEBUG (0)

For example:

```
Mongo::Logger.logger.level = Logger::WARN
```

reference:
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#class-Logger-label-Description

Answer (score 0):

Use `:heartbeat_frequency` instead of `:heartbeat`

Comment: Sorry that was a cut-and-paste error on my part.  The code indeed uses "heartbeat_frequency"